# Can I use dial up modem to connect to internet while installing ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: internet

Can I use dial up modem to connect to internet while installing Ubuntu?

I use Huawei EC156 modem to connect to the internet.

Comment: yes you can setup dial-up and install ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a live USB/CD and select ' try ubuntu without install ' i use UNetbootin to create a live usb(you can use any other & you will still get the option).
[image]

After that you will get a screen like this [image]

At the top right corner you can set the network dial-up connection.[image]

After setting up dial-up connection run the "Install ubuntu icon " on desktop.